# Why does using .items() allows me to iterate through a defaultdict otherwise the variable is read wrong?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

When trying to iterate through a defaultdict my variables were read as strings when they should be read as lists, however, when I changed my code a little bit, it worked but I don't know exactly why. My defaultdict is a dictonary that has a list of dictionaries inside it. The code looked like that

```
for engagement in engagement_by_account:
 for engagement in engagement:
    engagement['total_minutes_visited'] = float(engagement['total_minutes_visited'])
```

And the error was:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However, when I changed the code to this:

```
for key,engagement in engagement_by_account.items():
 for engagement in engagement:
    engagement['total_minutes_visited'] = float(engagement['total_minutes_visited'])
```

there were no errors anymore.

Comment: Why are you naming the loop variable `engagement` on both the inner and outer loops? It may work in this case, but it's needlessly confusing/error-prone. It's not your problem here, but it's code smell. If nothing else, you could just name the outer one `engagements` (plural) and the inner `engagement` (singular) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you, I know that can confuse us in complex codes, but that one was too simple( at least I thought it was) that's why I left it that way.

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you iterate over a dictionary (or `defaultdict`), you will iterate over the *keys* of that dictionary. It seems here that you wanted to iterate over the values so you could either do what you did or something like:

```
for engagements in engagement_by_account.values():
  for engagement in engagements:
    engagement['total_minutes_visited'] = float(engagement['total_minutes_visited'])
```

Comment: It works too but actually I wanted to know why the other code (without .values or .items) doesn't work for defaultdict but works fine when I just try it with an ordinary dictionary like "dict = {}"

Comment: Are you sure no other part of your code changed? Aside from indexing non-existent keys, a `defaultdict` and a `dict` should behave identically in this case

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post screenshots but I tested several times, the only thing that changes when I remove the .values is the engagement variable from a dict on the .value case to a string on the other one.